# How to test firebase functions in saga?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, firebase-authentication, redux-saga

I'm trying to test the function below:

```
export function* signInWithEmail({ payload: { email, password } }) {
  try {
    const { user } = yield auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    yield call(getSnapShotFromUserAuth, user);
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(signInFailure(error));
  }
}
```

I have looked into `redux-saga-test-plan` as well as other saga testing libraries but can't seem to figure out how to test firebase function if it's not called with saga effects.

I need a way to mock firebase function at the same time being able to test that this line is being called `yield call(getSnapShotFromUserAuth, user);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use `jest.spyOn` for the firebase function and then verify the next step. Answer below:

```
it("should call getSnapShotFromUserAuth", () => {
    let userData = {
      user: {
        id: 1,
        name: "jon",
      },
    };

    let { user } = userData;

    jest
      .spyOn(auth, "signInWithEmailAndPassword")
      .mockImplementation(() => userData);

    let saga = testSaga(signInWithEmail, { payload });
    saga
      .next()
      .next({ user })
      .call(getSnapShotFromUserAuth, user)
      .next()
      .isDone();
  });
```